# Why I got sequence 2, 3, 1, 2, 3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
function App() {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('auth')) {
      setIsAuth(true)
      console.log('User Exists');
    }
    console.log('1');
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, [])
  console.log('2');

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuth, setIsAuth, isLoading }}>
      {console.log('3')}
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <AppRouter />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

In log I got sequence 2, 3, 1, 2, 3. I expected 1, 2, 3. Why it is so?

Comment: Why did you expect 1, 2, 3? You have a _callback_, and the change of state means the component will render _at least_ twice.

Comment: If useEffect is not asynchrous. It should display 1 then 2,3

Comment: Then haven't you just learned that `useEffect` _is_ asynchronous?

Comment: Chatgpt said it is not asynchrous. It was wrong. I guess that react renders first code that has a higher priority

Comment: Then what have you learned about trusting ChatGPT? There's a reason it's [banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/3001761), its ability to create plausible-seeming text far outstrips its ability to actually be correct.

Comment: @aljustiet: *"Chatgpt said it is not asynchrous."* - Then I guess you should ask ChatGPT to clarify, and provide you with an example to demonstrate its assertion?

Comment: "*Chatgpt said*" I mean - that's your mistake there. Pretty much any programmer with any sensibility has declared ChatGPT completely unreliable. That's also why *you should be doing at least the barest amount of research before posting*. Reading the documentation on `useEffect` should have been enough. That's not much to ask, either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let me explain to you in detail.

As per the react flow, the first render will be called then any hooks will be called, see below chart.

Credits: https://github.com/donavon/hook-flow/blob/master/hook-flow.pdf

[image]

1. First Component will run that is why its log `2`.
2. It will run the render method and in render method you have console `3` so it will log `3` there.
3. Now it will run `useEffect` hook so at that time, it will log `1`.
4. You set `setIsLoading` state to false so rerender will happen and it will trigger the `App` component again, so now it will print `2` and then `3`.